# form_with model parameter for nested resources Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I'm new to Rails (and Stackoverflow) so pardon my question.

I'm confused by `<%= form_with(model: [ @article, @article.comments.build ], local: true) do |form| %>` in the "Getting started with rails" guide.

1. The [guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) mentioned `[@article, @article.comments.build]` "builds a nested route", but how does it do so?
2. As mentioned in [edgeguides](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) `model: @article` passes the actual object `@article` into the form. So how can we pass a nested route to the model parameter?

Thanks in advance for your guidance and patience!

**UPDATE** 
After much research, I've made the following progress

[`build`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb#L128) is an alias for `new`.

`[@article, @article.comments.build]` is an array

Parameter `model` takes in an instance of a class (in this case `comment`), and infers the scope (`:comment`) and url (`article_comments_path(@article)`). Because the instance passed into it is new, rails infers the method to be `post` [Source](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with)

So how does the hash `[@article, @article.comments.build]` return an instance of class `comment`, while telling rails the correct URL (article_comments_path(@article))?

Answer (score 1):

In `edgeguides`, only namespace routing example is provided, not as nested routing example.

When you pass `[@article, @article.comments.build]`, it consider url for associated object `comment` by taking it as nested route.

This is advantage of `form_with` over `form_for`

Comment: Url for CommentsController#create is created (by passing article_id) & in params you will have only `article_id` from which you can get `@article` object & `params[:comment]` for creating `@comment`

Comment: Hmm so does `[@article, @article.comments.build]` return a URL  or an instance of the class `comment`? And if it's the former, how does `model` handle it?

Comment: passing `[@article, @article.comments.build]` to form_with you indicate it that it's nested routes for `articles` & `comments` & pass `article_id` and with submit it carry comments params

Comment: Hi ray, I appreciate your prompt feedback, but I'm still struggling to understand how the hash magically turns into an instance of class comment, while retaining the URL. (details in my edit)

Comment: No, it did not create any instance of `Comment` object using hash, it just passes `'comment' => { 'name' => 'roy', 'age' => '24' }`  in `params`. So you have to explicitly create `@article = Article.find(params[:article_id]); @comment = @article.comments.new(comment_params)`  where `comment_params` is method to provide whitelisted comment parameters

Comment: "No, it did not create any instance of Comment object using hash, it just passes 'comment' => { 'name' => 'roy', 'age' => '24' } in params"

But it passes the hash as an argument into model, not params. 

"So you have to explicitly create @article = Article.find(params[:article_id]); @comment = @article.comments.new(comment_params) where comment_params is method to provide whitelisted comment parameters" 

The interesting thing is that `@comment = @article.comments.new(comment_params)` **isn't** in my controller. It is created in the partial for form through `build`

Comment: [@article, @article.comments.build] provide netsed url by these 2 objects & provide  `article_id` to url only.

Comment: I truly appreciate your patience ray but my question remains: why does `model` accept a url as a parameter (instead of an actual instance of the class).

Comment: `form_with` is helper which take hash argument as a first argument to build url (with/without id), when hash argument provided has key `model`, it takes its value to build url by rails convention. Now in this case, you have provided array of 2 arguments to `model` key which create nested route url `article/3/comments`

Comment: `form_with` is helper which take hash argument as a first argument to build url (with/without id), when hash argument provided has key `model`, it takes its value to build url by rails convention. Now in this case, you have provided array of 2 arguments to `model` key which create nested route url

Comment: But this [https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with] states that form_with has 5 parameters: model, scope, url, format, options. It can take in a hash as its first argument, but it must go into one of these parameters. In the same docs, it states that rails infer the scope and url from the model. Thus the model parameter must accept an instance of the class, and not a URL.

Comment: Yes some of them are optional also but notice one thing, they are strictly ordered. First is for url

Comment: Yes some of them are optional also but notice one thing, they are strictly ordered. First is for url

Comment: `form_with(model: nil, scope: nil, url: nil, format: nil, **options)` First parameter is model :(

Comment: first parameter is hash and later all are in array of `options`.. first hash argument have 4 keys and when `url` key is nil then it create url by reference of `model` key